# How to run jquery sortable in localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The URL : https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

I download and run it on localhost, but it's not working

I run example.html

My URL is like this :  `http://localhost/ngetest/drag_drop/source/example.html`

The result :

[image]

I update example.html to be like this :

```
<style type="text/css">
    body.dragging, body.dragging * {
      cursor: move !important;
    }

    .dragged {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.5;
      z-index: 2000;
    }

    ol.example li.placeholder {
      position: relative;
      /** More li styles **/
    }
    ol.example li.placeholder:before {
      position: absolute;
      /** Define arrowhead **/
    }
</style>

<ol class='example'>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
<script src='js/jquery-sortable.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function  () {
      $("ol.example").sortable();
    });
</script>
```

But just the same. It's not working

Thank you

Comment: Check your browser console do you get any error?

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include jQuery. Kindly include it.

Comment: Please check console, you have included jquery-sortable which in turn depends on jquery library. Please include that too.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, I'm sorry

Comment: @mosestoh You are welcome! `:)`

Comment: I didn't understand that @mosestoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly fine:

```js
$(function  () {
  $("ol.example").sortable();
});
```

```css
body.dragging, body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ol.example li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  /** More li styles **/
}
ol.example li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  /** Define arrowhead **/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/application.js"></script>

<ol class='example'>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I need you help, Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640041/how-to-validation-of-input-text-field-in-ajax?noredirect=1#comment58961736_35640041

Answer (score 1):

The reason when it didn't work on `localhost` its because maybe you didn't include `jQuery`

```js
$(function  () {
  $("ol.example").sortable();
});
```

```css
      body.dragging, body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ol.example li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  /** More li styles **/
}
ol.example li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  /** Define arrowhead **/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sortable</title>
</head>

<body>
   <ol class='example'>
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
   <li>Third</li>
    </ol>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it does. Why ask?

Comment: Yer @PraveenKumar, I have seen the different but for the main point is to point out that he forgot to include jQuery  to his project.

Comment: Yup.. That's fine. My mistake. Sorry.