# How to validation of input text field in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My javascript code is like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url:base_url+"agent_control/manage_booking/get_pax",
    type: "post",
    data: {id: id},
    success:function(data) {
        App.unblockUI();
        var code = JSON.parse(data);
        var isitable;
        var j;
        for(var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
            j = i + 1;
            isitable += '<tr>';
            isitable += '<td>'+code[i].transactionpax_title+' '+code[i].transactionpax_firstname+' '+code[i].transactionpax_lastname+'</td>';
            isitable += '<td><input type="text" id="tiket_number_'+i+'" class="form-control required" /></td>';
            isitable += '</tr>';
        }
        isitable += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn blue dropdown-toggle submit_tiket_number" id="'+id+'" data="'+code.length+'" /></td></tr>';
        $("#data_tiket_number").find("tbody").html(isitable);
        $('#data_tiket_number').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Look here : `<input type="text" id="tiket_number_'+i+'" class="form-control required" />`

I had add required in text input. But it's not working
If the text input is empty, when I click submit there was no message required

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: In which sense does this not work?

Comment: If you have some event handlers for `input.required`  then I suggest you that  you use proper event delegation. like `$(document).on('event', 'input.required', function(){});`

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, In my opinion, it does not work because the text input in ajax

Comment: instead of `<input type="text" id="tiket_number_'+i+'" class="form-control required" />`, use `<input type="text" id="tiket_number_'+i+'" class="form-control" required />` to use the native browser validation

Comment: @mosestoh is this table part of a `<form>`..? If so, did you try mylee's suggestion..? Make sure your document id HTML5

Comment: @mosestoh Has it been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do three things:

1. make sure you have form around your table
2. move `required` out of the class
3. change your button type from `button` to `submit`

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/cjvu819L/)

```
for(var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    isitable += '<tr>';
    isitable += '<td>'+code[i].transactionpax_title+' '+code[i].transactionpax_firstname+' '+code[i].transactionpax_lastname+'</td>';
    isitable += '<td><input type="text" id="tiket_number_'+i+'" class="form-control" required/></td>';
    isitable += '</tr>';
}
isitable += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn blue dropdown-toggle submit_tiket_number" id="'+id+'" data="'+code.length+'" /></td></tr>';
```

Comment: I can't see this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126170/how-to-implement-redis-in-codeigniter

Comment: It is okay. Thank you

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175735/how-to-get-data-in-function-extend-controller