# How to implement Redis in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis

I get the tutorial in:

http://yaminnoor.com/redis-codeigniter/

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html#redis

I try it like this:

Config (`application\config\redis.php`):

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['socket_type'] = 'tcp'; //`tcp` or `unix`
$config['socket'] = '/var/run/redis.sock'; // in case of `unix` socket type
$config['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; //change this to match your amazon redis cluster node endpoint
$config['password'] = NULL;
$config['port'] = 6379;
$config['timeout'] = 0;
```

Controller:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Redis_tes extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'redis', 'backup' => 'file'));
    }

    public function index() {
        // die('tes');
        if($this->cache->redis->is_supported() || $this->cache->file->is_supported()) {
            $var1 = $this->cache->get('cache_var1');
        } else {
            $cache_var1 = $this->_model_data->get_var1();
            $this->cache->save('cache_var1', $cache_var1);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I run `http://localhost/app_redis/redis_tes`, which produces the following error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Invalid driver requested: CI_Cache_redis

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: not so sure what this means but @first i would take a look whether the file is here or not - take a look @/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/ - is there a Cache_redis file ?

and which version of CI do you use ?

Comment: Making use of this package: https://github.com/Maykonn/codeigniter-predis

Answer (score 3):

Look here:
https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis
Try to use this library.

Update : This library is deprecated. Author recommends to migrate on Predis.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: From the repo README: "This library is deprecated. We recommend migrating to Predis."

Comment: The following library makes use of Predis and provides a lot of cool features: https://github.com/Maykonn/codeigniter-predis